# Stop ViewPager from scrolling to see the last page

Tags: android

I have a `ViewPager` which i populate with 4 items. I need it to be scrollable until the 3rd item (inclusive) but when the user tries to move to the 4th one it should just not let him. 
When he validates the 3 pages, only then i need to allow him to move to the 4th.

Don't ask why, it's complicated, but I can't instantiate and set the 4th page to the adapter only AFTER the first 3 are validated. That would solve my problem, indeed. I need to have it already available in the list.

Any suggestions?

I tried playing around with onPageScrolled() to see if I can stop it from moving forward even a pixel, but I wasn't able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
      if(!isAccess) {
        return 3;
      } else {
        return 4;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I need to wait 10 minutes to Approve the answer, but that will do the trick, definitely !

Comment: @AndreiBogdan are facing any issue bro in this still ?

Comment: Hah! So ... i just implemented it and it's not really quite right. Initially it's non-existent, not yet instantiated 'cause it's size()-1 from the beginning. After i set it to size() it gets instantiated but the viewpager can be dragged to the last item but it immediately scrolls back to the 3rd page. 'wonder if there's a way to keep it from moving still ...

Comment: But i decided to re-accept the answer, it's fine ... ain't nobody got time to waste on it any longer.